# Tensorflow.js - TypeError: e.forEach is not a function

Tags: javascript, tensorflow, tensorflow.js

I'm new to tensorflow.js, I've used the Python version before and now I'm converting my previously trained models to web.

I followed this [codelabs tutorial](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/tensorflowjs-convert-python-savedmodel#5).

The code is pretty simple, I have the index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

    <head>
        <title>Testing the JS Model</title>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow/tfjs@3.6.0/dist/tf.min.js"></script>
        <script src="scripttest.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>

    </body>

</html>
```

In the scripttest.js I have:

```
const MODEL_URL = "../model/model.json"

async function run() {
    // Load the model from the CDN.
    const model = await tf.loadLayersModel(MODEL_URL, strict=false);
    
    // Print out the architecture of the loaded model.
    // This is useful to see that it matches what we built in Python.
    console.log(model.summary());

    // Create a 1 dimensional tensor with our test value.
    const input = tf.tensor1d([TEST_VALUE]);

    // Actually make the prediction.
    const result = model.predict(input);
}

run();
```

But when I run it I get this error:

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: e.forEach is not a function
    at bg (util_base.js:681)
    at Mw (tensor_ops_util.js:44)
    at Lw (tensor.js:56)
    at Ww (io_utils.js:225)
    at RM (models.js:334)
    at models.js:316
    at c (runtime.js:63)
    at Generator._invoke (runtime.js:293)
    at Generator.next (runtime.js:118)
    at bv (runtime.js:747)
```

If you want to see it running by yourself I've put it into my [website](http://hugosouza.com/test_tfjs/).

Can you tell me what's wrong here? Is it a problem with my converted model or could it be some bug?

Since it doesnt't outputs anything in the `console.log(model.summary())` I'm suspecting it's caused by the `await tf.loadLayersModel(MODEL_URL, strict=false);` line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to input any value for the `TEST_VALUE`

```
const MODEL_URL = "../model/model.json"

async function run() {
    // Load the model from the CDN.
    const model = await tf.loadLayersModel(MODEL_URL);

    const TEST_VALUE = 950.0
    
    // Print out the architecture of the loaded model.
    // This is useful to see that it matches what we built in Python.
    console.log(model.summary());

    // Create a 1 dimensional tensor with our test value.
    const input = tf.tensor1d([TEST_VALUE]);

    // Actually make the prediction.
    const result = model.predict(input);
}

run();
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I just put this value but I'm still getting the same error.
It's not related to the ```const input = tf.tensor1d([TEST_VALUE]);``` line. 

This error is being thrown before ```console.log(model.summary());``` is printed, which makes me think that this is happening at ```const model = await tf.loadLayersModel(MODEL_URL, strict=false);``` line.

The weirdest thing is that in none of those files that appear in the error message there is any ```e.forEach``` function.

Comment: Try removing `strict=False`.

Comment: Didn't work, I'm still getting the same error message

Comment: Could you try upgrading Tensorflow.js?

Comment: I'm already using the latest version I think, I had imported the 3.6.0 version from https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow/tfjs@3.6.0/dist/tf.min.js

Comment: @HugoSouza could you check that the `MODEL_URL` is correct?

Comment: yes, the ```MODEL_URL``` leads to https://hugosouza.com/model/model.json, and the .bin files are also in https://hugosouza.com/model/